# Do I need static variables in a singleton class?

Tags: c++, singleton

Take the below code. If I were to add some private member data into this class, say a std::vector, would I make it static or not?

```
#include <string>

class Logger{
public:
   static Logger* Instance();
   bool openLogFile(std::string logFile);
   void writeToLogFile();
   bool closeLogFile();

private:
   Logger(){};  // Private so that it can  not be called
   Logger(Logger const&){};             // copy constructor is private
   Logger& operator=(Logger const&){};  // assignment operator is private
   static Logger* m_pInstance;
};
```

**Code example shamelessly taken from [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatically, no. Other than that, there's nothing that keeps you from doing it.

Keep in mind though that if it is `static`, it needs to be defined and the member gets initialized before entry to `main`, when the program starts.

If it isn't `static`, it will get initialized when `m_pInstance` gets created (which can be useful if you need some lazy initialization).

Comment: If it is `static`, it may not be constructed before `m_pInstance` is created.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is order of initialization.  In C++, the singleton idiom
is usually used to resolve order of initialization issues, so that's
likely to be a problem: if the members are static, you can't be sure
that they have been constructed before you try to use them.